# function in jquery where one class have multiple elements dynamicaly generated

Tags: jquery

I have search the previous question but couldn't find the answer.

Dynamically generated html:

```
<a class="finddiv" id="#div_0">date1</a>
<a class="finddiv" id="#div_1">date1</a>
<a class="finddiv" id="#div_2">date1</a>
```

hidden div which i have to open- on cllick of above link:

```
<div id="div_0" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="div_1" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="div_2" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I want to open the `div` with `id` `div_o` by clicking of anchor tag with class name `find`, I am using the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.find').delegate(this, 'click', function() {
        var ids = $(this).attr('id');
        $(ids).slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

But above function is running as many time as the number of elements in the class "find".
In above case 3 times. I just want to run the function once. I have also used "one", "live"
properties in jquery but nothing has happened. Since the content is dynamic I can not use the id attribute to call jquery function.

Comment: By the way the classname `find` does not exist in the example above. Did you mean to use the `finddiv`?

Comment: @user972809: Check out http://jsbeautifier.org. Quick easy way to clean up your JavaScript formatting.

Comment: yes i am using findviv but forgot to show here

Comment: By 'Dynamically generated' do you mean client-side or server-side?

Comment: THank You to everyone for giving such a wonderful support,the problem rather sillyness was of me that my script function was under a foreach loop that;s why it was running multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `delegate` mixed up:

> ```
> $(document).delegate('a.finddiv', 'click', function(){
>     $(this.id).slideToggle();
>     return false;
> });
> ```
>
> Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/AZCky/

Attaching like this also means you don't need to place it inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: still multiple times please help me

Comment: @user972809: AndyE and the rest of the people here won't be able to be much help if you don't show the code that is causing your issue.

Comment: @user972809: it [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/AZCky/).  Did you make any changes to the code when you posted it to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `delegate` here, a simple `.click` will work just fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.finddiv').click(function(){
        var ids = $(this).attr('id');
        $(ids).slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/djweQ/

You only need to use `.delegate` if the elements are added to the DOM at a later point.  Try it like this (you can change `'body'` if you want, as long as it's a parent of the `<a>` tags):

```
$('body').delegate('a.finddiv', 'click', function() {
    var ids = $(this).attr('id');
    $(ids).slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: He said the `<a>` elements were dynamically generated, so delegation *is* necessary.

Comment: @user972809: How is that possible?  In the demo I posted it runs once.  You sure you aren't binding it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

In your markup the class name is not `find` but it is `finddiv` so you should use `finddiv` in the javascript code to find the anchor element. Also the way you are using delegate is wrong. Since the anchor elements are generated dynamically you should have a delegate on the document object. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).delegate('a.finddiv', 'click', function(){
           var ids = $(this).attr('id');
           $(ids).slideToggle();
           return false;
        });
});
```

As a side note. Instead of using `id` as attribute in the anchor element to maintain the id of the div to slide toggle you can use `href` attribute and get the `href` attribute inside `click` handler.

Comment: yes i have used finddiv but it is running three times means for every element in that class the function is running  i just want to call it for the current cliked element in the class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").delegate(".finddiv", "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('id')).slideToggle();
});
```

If your `.finddiv` elements have a direct parent into which they are dynamically apended, use the selector for that instead of `body` as you will get much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your initial mark-up has what appears to be duplicate `id`'s. The `id` attribute has to be unique. What I'd suggest would be to use the following:

```
<!---------dynamicaly generated html------------>
<a class="finddiv" id="a_0">
date1
</a>
<a class="finddiv" id="a_1">
date1
</a>
<a class="finddiv" id="a_2">
date1
</a>

<!---------hidden div which i have to open- on cllick of above link----->
<div id="a_0_div" style="display:none;">  
</div>
<div id="a_1_div" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="a_2_div" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.finddiv').click(function(event) {
        var divId = $(this).attr('id') + '_div';
        $(divId).slideToggle();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

As an alternative, each `<a>` tag doesn't need an `id` attribute, you could use:

```
<!---------dynamicaly generated html------------>
<a class="finddiv" data-open="div0">
date1
</a>
<a class="finddiv" data-open="div1">
date1
</a>
<a class="finddiv" data-open="div2">
date1
</a>

<!---------hidden div which i have to open- on cllick of above link----->
<div id="div0" style="display:none;">  
</div>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.finddiv').click(function(event) {
        $($(this).data('open')).slideToggle();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Though this will only work in JQuery 1.7 onwards

Comment: The `id` attributes on the `<a>` elements aren't duplicates, because they're prefixed with *#*.  This also means that your code won't work, because you're not prefixing the ID selector lookups with *#*.

Comment: But the `#` character isn't valid in `id` atttibutes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: I stand corrected - HTML5 specifies only [non-space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: correct, and browsers have always allowed this behaviour for `id` attributes — HTML5 just makes it official :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.finddiv').click(function(){

  $($(this.attr('id')).show());

});
```